# how to array key start from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: php, arrays, range

How do I start the array of a range at 1 instead of 0,
Code looks like this:

```
    $numbers = range(0, 14);
```

I tried this but that does not solve my problem

```
    $numbers = range(0, 14);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, but couldn't you just use `range(1, 14)` instead?

Comment: You want the `key`s to be `1 - 14`?

Comment: if I start at 1 the array index still starts at 0 => 1. I want to start it like this 1=> 1

Comment: I got the question, but its just ridiculously bad explained, and the second example is same as first FYI or im blind, you're lucky people are still willing to answer :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also go for :

```
$numbers = range(0, 14);

array_unshift($numbers,"");
unset($numbers[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$numbers = array_combine(range(1,14), range(1,14));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code These will help you**

```
$data = array_slice(range(0,12), 1, null, true);
```